# Migration from Tomcat6 to Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6

I have a legacy web application which works perfectly fine on tomcat 6. In this application, we have a servlet, say DefaultServlet which has following mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>defaultServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>the.bhushan.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>defaultServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now when no other url mapping is matched, then this defaultServlet is get invoked. This is my requirement.
In tomcat7, I used same servlet, the.bhushan.servlets.DefaultServlet and put @WebServlet("/") annotation on that servlet but this servlet is not getting called as it was getting called in tomcat6.

Answer (score 0):

Open web.xml and change the version numbers of the servlet api to "3.0":

```
<web-app metadata-complete="false" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" >
```

Set metadata-complete="false" to make sure the server will scan for annotated classes.

Make sure your class still extends "HttpServlet".

Make sure you dont have additional servlet-api.jar files in your app.

Comment: Hi @Stefan, I made changes as per you suggestion. But still no luck. Strange thing is that when I change @WebServlet("/") to @WebServlet("/*") then this serlvet is getting called but it get called for all requests, which is what I dont want.

Comment: What is the DefaultServlet doing, MVC? In that case map it to something like "/app/*".